# Natural homomorphism for tensor product ($\tau : G \mapsto $GL(Bilinear(V, W) )

Tags: group-theory, tensor-products, abstract-algebra

I'm struggling to understand why the following function $\tau$ is a homomorphism:

> Given homomorphisms $\rho : G\rightarrow GL(V)$ and $\sigma : G\rightarrow
>  GL(W)$ where $V$ and $W$ are (finite-dimensional) vector spaces,
>    define $\tau : G\rightarrow GL(Bilinear(V,W))$, by
>
> $\tau (g)(L)(v,w) = L(\rho(g)^{-1}v,\ \sigma(g)^{-1}w)$ where $L\in
>  Bilinear(V,W)$, $v\in V$, and $w\in W$
>
> where $Bilinear(V, W)$ is the space of all bilinear forms on $V$ and
>    $W$[1].

By basic computation, I've found that

$\tau (gh)(L)(v,w) = L(\rho (h)^{-1}\rho(g)^{-1}v,\ \sigma (h)^{-1}\sigma(g)^{-1}w)$

while

$\tau (g)\tau (h)(L)(v,w) = L(\rho(g)^{-1}\rho(h)^{-1}v,\ \sigma(g)^{-1}\sigma(h)^{-1}w) = \tau(hg)(L)(v,w)$

I suspect that I'm failing to understand some fundamental property of bilinear forms that would allow me to manipulate the second expression differently - thanks for any and all help!

The answer to my question is probably buried in one of the responses to similar questions, but after puzzling over several of them I've lost hope.

[1]For whatever reason, the materials I am using uses this space of bilinear forms rather than the tensor product.

--

Edit: changed an asterisk into [1] because the asterisk looked like dual space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why they appeared in the wrong order is because you applied $\tau(g)$ and $\tau(h)$ to $L$ in the wrong order. Call $\tau(h)(L) = L'$ (since it is also a bilinear form). Then $(\tau(g)\tau(h))(L)$ is defined as $\tau(g) (\tau(h)(L)) = \tau(g)(L')$. The reason why it is defined like this is because the operation in $GL(V)$ is defined as composition of functions, thus has to be performed in ths order!

Now
$$
\tau(g)(L')(v,w) = L'(\rho(g)^{-1}v, \sigma(g)^{-1}w)
$$
and by the definition of $L'$, 
$$
L'(\rho(g)^{-1}v, \sigma(g)^{-1}w) = \tau(h)(L)(\rho(g)^{-1}v,\sigma(g)^{-1}(w)) = L(\rho(h)^{-1}\rho(g)^{-1}v, \sigma(h)^{-1}\sigma(g)^{-1}w).
$$
Hope that helps,